# Can you make it possible to embed and run code snippets other than JavaScript/HTML/CSS?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

This would really be great.

I saw people posting code that doesn't run because of syntax errors.

I told them that there are errors in the code but they didn't believe me.

I had to explain exactly which line doesn't run and why such a statement is not possible in this language.

It was really exhausting.

On [jdoodle](https://jdoodle.com) you can run code of many languages directly in your browser.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that's a good idea.

Most languages can't be ran in the client's browser. On sites like JDoodle, you're actually POSTing your code to their services, which then compiles and runs the code, and returns the result.

A service like that could be a significant added server load, and a *huge* security concern.

I'm pretty sure I've never seen a service like this that has the option to embed themselves in other sites, either.

Comment: I know they're run on their servers and not emulated using js. The snippet could be first run when the user clicks on a button. So crawlers or reloading the page won't trigger it. If you say it's a huge security concern how can jdoodle be capable of doing such a thing?

Comment: @somega: It's JDoodle's one and only concern. It's their core business. They have experts specialized in running this kind of service. Just as SE is outsourcing image hosting, I don't think SE should do this (themselves).

Comment: If you think big effort is a problem for se then take a look at se chat...

Comment: Building a chat is not something you can compare with hosting a service like this where you can submit, compile, _run_ and return arbitrary code in _many_ languages. It's a completely different set of problems.

Comment: Well, there is this https://tio.run website, which I believed is sponsorized by the people at codegolf.SE, which could be used as a backend for SE to support this, without increasing the load on SE's own servers. I believe it has an API available somewhere. Not sure tio.run server can handle the increase of load it would induce, though. But the idea is interesting, and the efforts on SE side would be limited. I'm pretty sure the people at the CodeGolf site would love to see that integrated.

Comment: @dimlostfaithinSE I didn't know tio. The list of supported languages is amazing...

Comment: I think there should be some web services that provide free api for running many languages for the case of public source code, like that on stackoverflow. They might allow stackoverflow to use their servers for running code.

Comment: Business ethics aside, there is no _free_ API that will work on the scale SE would need it to work. It'd be pricy...